# firebase offline lost focus on input

Tags: javascript, iphone, firebase, offline-caching

I've a web app on iphone developed with a firebase backend (JavaScript client v2.2.4)

When I open the app with airplane mode activated (no network) the app is loading fine, everything is cached with a cache.manifest

I can see in the safari's console that the firebase client is making calls to my firebase backend. Those calls are failing because I don't have any network.

the calls looks like this : /.lp?start=t&ser=17611300&cb=10&v=5

The issue:

If the user put the focus in a textarea, the focus is lost everytime the firebase calls are failing, which is very annoying for the user

Any idea how to avoid this behaviour?

The specificity of my use case:

- I'm offline
- The user put a focus in a textarea

Comment: Yeah, so, judging by the lack of similar questions, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that this isn't widespread, is probably specific to your use case, there's not enough info here to reproduce or understand this problem, and it's going to take some troubleshooting and narrowing of the scope to get close to an answer.

Comment: Hi, the question has been been updated with more details

Comment: See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround

I found that `/.lp?start=t&ser=17611300&cb=10&v=5` is for long pooling connections

Websockets is enough for me, so I force the websocket only with the following code

```
Firebase.INTERNAL.forceWebSockets();
```

The problem vanished